# write JSON to file as lazy ByteString directly from Aeson encode output without converting to String

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, lazy-io

Currently, I'm using something like this to write JSON content (`my_json`) to a file (`my_output_filepath`):

```
import           Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 as U

writeFile my_output_filepath $ U.toString $ encodePretty my_json
```

This works, but I'm wondering whether it is necessary to convert the `ByteString` that is returned by (`encodePretty`) to a `String` before writing it to a file, or if it incurs a performance penalty.

I see [there is a variant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:writeFile) of `writeFile` that accepts a `ByteString` as input.  However, when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘B.ByteString’
            with actual type ‘U.ByteString’
NB: ‘B.ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
    ‘U.ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
```

Is there some way to get the `Lazy` variant of `ByteString` to interoperate with `writeFile`?

Comment: Could you please post the part of your source code which causes the error? I can't see where the strict bytestring comes from, `encodePretty` returns lazy bytestring and `writeFile` from `Data.ByteString.Lazy` expects lazy bytestring as well.

Comment: Could it be that you're importing the `writeFile` from the strict bytestring module `Data.ByteString`? Make sure you're definitely using the lazy one you linked to.

Comment: that not enough? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:hPut

Comment: @WillSewell you are correct.  D'oh.